# How to divide this kind of algebraic equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am having following equation to divide

$2y(y + 3) = 9x \tag{i}$

$y(y - 2) = 3x \tag{ii}$

I don't know how to divide (i) by (ii) and find x?

I've got this question from [indiabix](https://www.indiabix.com/aptitude/time-and-distance/discussion-442)

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to solve the equations?  I ask because dividing them isn't the way to go.

Comment: @user951215 What have you tried? There are many ways you can make your question more well-received - adding context, or even where you got the question from might help anyone answering the question.

Comment: https://www.indiabix.com/aptitude/time-and-distance/discussion-442

Comment: Multiply the 2nd eq by 3 and subtract the first eq from the 2nd. This gives you an eq in y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $y=0$ then $x=0$

If $y=2$ then $x=0$ and $x=20/9$ impossible.

Assume $y\ne 0$ and $y\ne 2$. then by division ,

$$\frac {2y (y+3)}{y (y-2)}=\frac {9x}{3x}=3$$

or after simplification,
$$\frac {2 (y+3)}{y-2}=3$$
$$\implies 2 (y+3)=3 (y-2) $$
$$\implies y=12$$
$$3x=y (y-2)=120$$
$$\implies x=40$$

Comment: Why i have to divide them can i solve it by adding or subtract

Comment: You don't have to divide -  you can multiply equation (ii) by $3$. You can see what I mean by looking at my post (which is at the bottom). This is a more convenient method, because you can directly see one equation is $3$ times that of the other.

Comment: Yeah i am clear now tnx to toby mak and all of you

Comment: Don't forget - you can *accept* an answer by clicking on the green arrow below the voting bar. People usually accept an answer when an answer has answered their question well.

Comment: $110\%$ complete :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt $110 % $ exists in $\Bbb C $ not in $\Bbb R $.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that (ii) is twice that of (i). Since $3 * (ii)$ is equal to $9x$, we can set (i) and $3*(ii)$ equal to each other, and then solve for $y$:

$$3y(y-2) = 2y(y+3)$$
$$3y^2-6y = 2y^2+6y$$
$$y^2-12y = 0$$

Now you have a quadratic equation with no constant term. Once you solve for $y$, you can substitute that value back into either one of the two equation to get $x$.

Comment: The advantage being that we don't need to care about anything. $\to +1$

Comment: Dividing by zero certainly has plenty of problems... thanks for the upvote @ClaudeLeibovici!

Answer (score 1):

1. We have $x=0 \iff y=0$
2. If $y \ne 0$ then we  have $\frac{2y(y+3)}{y(y-2)}=\frac{9x}{3x}=3$,

hence

$\frac{2(y+3)}{y-2}=3$

From this you can compute $y$ and then, by (i) or (ii) you can find x